# Google Map with Local Churches, how to construct API call?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

Is there are way to retrieve a map from Google using the API so that it displays a list of local churches with churches with markers?

I have the basic syntax, and I have a basic API account setup, but I am not how/if I can use the type field.

```
var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng("-33.8670522", "151.1957362"),
    zoom: 11,
    scrollwheel: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googlemaps"), mapOptions);
```

Comment: I was hoping that I could just create a map and specify a type or keywords and have google return a map with markers.  I do know how to create map markers if google would return locations via a JSON API call, but that is a bit more work.  :)

Comment: You could try passing a "church" to search in the general area. However, they make their PLACES api just for this. I'm not sure how much they are pushing that.

Comment: This kind of thing works for an JSON request:

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=44.895222,-93.397745&radius=5000&keyword=churches&key=myKey

But I'm not sure what the radius units are, and I guess I would have to parse the request and make markers to overlay the map ?

Comment: @sscotti I posted an answer, take a look. Snippet doesn't works here (maybe due the callback), so copy the source and run locally. See if this is what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this, using [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places).

I'll use [JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript), since you seem to have a map being built with such API.

As said in [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#loading_the_library):

> The Places service is a self-contained library, separate from the main Maps API JavaScript code. To use the functionality contained within this library, you must first load it using the libraries parameter in the Maps API bootstrap URL:
>
> ```
> <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
> ```

After this, using JavaScript Places API you can request places by type and a radius (in meters). The maximum allowed radius is 50.000 meters.

Here a piece of code that demonstrate this:

```
var request = {
    location: sydney,
    radius: 5000,
    types: ['church']
};

var service = new gm.places.PlacesService(map);
service.nearbySearch(request, handlePlaceResponse);
```

**Obs.**: In this example, **`handlePlaceResponse`** is a callback to handle the response and create the markers. See in the complete example how it works.

This will request by **churches** in a 5km radius from Sydney point (`lat:` -33.8670522, `lng:` 151.1957362).

To overlay markers you'll need handle the response. In the example I used only `name` to put as content of [`InfoWindow`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows). You can see details about the response here: [Place Details Responses](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details_responses)

So, a function to create markers look like this:

```
/**
 * Creates marker with place information from response
 */
function createMarker(place) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: place.geometry.location
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(place.name);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
}
```

Also, if you need, for types supported in place search, see this link: [Place Type](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types)

Here an example using as point the used by you and 5000 meters for `radius`:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Google Maps - Places Sample</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
        #map {
            height: 600px;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
    <script>
        var gm = google.maps;
        
        var map;
        var bounds;
        var service;
        var infowindow;
        
        var sydney = new gm.LatLng(-33.8670522, 151.1957362);

        function initialize() {
            var options = {
                zoom: 15,
                center: sydney,
                mapTypeId: gm.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                streetViewControl: false,
                scrollwheel: false
            };

            map = new gm.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);
            
            var request = {
                location: sydney,
                radius: 5000,
                types: ['church']
            };

            bounds = new gm.LatLngBounds();
            infowindow = new gm.InfoWindow();
            service = new gm.places.PlacesService(map);
            service.nearbySearch(request, handlePlaceResponse);
        }
        
        /**
         * Handle place response and call #createMarker to creat marker for every place returned
         */
        function handlePlaceResponse(results, status) {
            if (status == gm.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    createMarker(results[i]);
                }
            }
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
            map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
        }

        /**
         * Creates marker with place information from response
         */
        function createMarker(place) {
            var location = place.geometry.location;
            var marker = new gm.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: location
            });
            
            bounds.extend(location);

            gm.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.setContent(place.name);
                infowindow.open(map, this);
            });
        }

        gm.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, is there anyway get this as json formatted list like we use in google maps api EX https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=7.08295450557229, 80.00561767163424&radius=5000&type=Churches&keyword=Churches&key=API_KEY